# How can I access the Flores reference to show each of their children? On Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

```
 db
|
Categories
  |
  Flowers
    |
     01
    |   |
        |
    |   name:"example"
    |   imagen:"example"
    |
    02
     |
      name:"example"
      imagen:"example"
```

This is the structure of the db and what I want is to show the elements of Flowers
[image]

```
public class Regalos extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Categorias").child("Flores");





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_regalos);

        mRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Regalo,ViewHolderRegalo> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Regalo, ViewHolderRegalo>(
                Regalo.class,
                R.layout.item_regalo,
                ViewHolderRegalo.class,
                mFirebaseDataBase

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolderRegalo viewHolder, final  Regalo model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setDetail(getApplicationContext(),model.getDescripcion(),model.getImagen(),model.getCosto(),model.getSku());

            }
        };
        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try calling `firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening()` in your `onStart()` method.

Comment: Also: Can you show us your Regalo class?

Comment: yes, please post Regalo class

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` class with for constructor is a very old version. Try to use the latest one, as explained in the example above.